# How do I call a function from a custom button in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, function

I am trying to make my custom button call a function when clicked. `[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(functionToCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` doesn't work for mybutton. I am creating this button from an already existing custom button. I cannot change the methods for this custom button. I guess what I want to know is if it is possible to call an entity like a custom button on any view without using addTarget:self action:@selector(function:).

Comment: You need to show more information. How do you create `myButton` and add it to the view hierarchy. Show `functionToCall`. What happens when you tap the button?

Comment: I'm afraid your question still isn't clear. You don't show *the code* where this button is created or how you get a reference to the button.  What is the context (function) where you have the code you have shown?  A common problem in Objective C is sending messages to `nil` - this doesn't crash, it just doesn't do anything. What does it mean "I am creating this button from an already existing button"? See [ask]

Comment: I am not clear about your ask and I checked answer also. if nothing goes in your favour, try to add gesture on your custom button. Use this gesture callback to perform your action.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of demo code that you can refer to

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setupUI];

    _closeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_closeBtn setImage:TTGetImage(@"close") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_closeBtn setImage:TTGetImage(@"close") forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_closeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(clickCloseBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)clickCloseBtn {
    NSLog(@"clickCloseBtn");
}
```

Comment: This is for a regular button of type UIButton. My custom button doesn't work with addTarget. That's what I mentioned above. If anyone has something that's not with addTarget. Let me know. thanks

Comment: did your btn‘s super class is UIControl? @Rhaystack